# Trying to make custom directive with Angular 1.4.9 but stuck with link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

First of all this is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/JbG6vlSbeWrBcmYhmhF1?p=preview

I'm trying to make directive to add floating label as shown in this [example](http://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/LNvMYK) to any input field.

For example I have the following input field:

```
<input floating-label placeholder="Better field" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="floatingDirective"/>
```

`floating-label` should work in such way that it will expand it to the following code:

```
<div class="field">
        <label ng-show="betterField" class="show-hide">Better field</label>
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="betterField" placeholder="Better field"/>
</div>
```

And I can't achieve this, this is my directive so far:

```
.directive('floatingLabel', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
                var wrapper = '<div class="field">' + 
                                '</div>';

                element.after($compile('<label ng-show="' + attrs.ngModel + '" class="show-hide">' + attrs.placeholder + '</label>')(scope));
                element.wrap(wrapper);
            }
        }}
 )
```

Can't realize how to combine `wrap`, `prepend` and `append` to get desired structure and how to make `ng-show` work with `ng-model`'s value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a slight restructure to make this work [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IOuiUHpuBtVTjCydPm1g?p=preview).

I think your directive should handle creating the input and the label so that you don't have to worry about the link function and you have better control over the scope. That would look like this...

```
angular.module('baseapp.directives',[])
angular.module('baseapp.directives')
.directive('floatingLabelInput', function (){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                placeholder: '@'
            },
            template: `<div class="field"><input floating-label placeholder="Better field" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel"/><label ng-show="ngModel" class="show-hide">{{placeholder}}</label></div>`
        }
}
 )
```

Then in your html you just do this...

```
<floating-label-input ng-model="floatingDirective" placeholder="Better field"></floating-label-input>
```

Comment: Actually your solution work and I thought about it but I'd like to do it in a way I intended, otherwise our team should do a lot of work to replace all input fields, also for another form elements I need to do another directives. I'll accept your answer in a few days if nobody will give another.